# Run VLookup function housed within a VBA Macro Button

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I've been working on a Vlookup function (that works within a cell) as shown below:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2&"*", 'Sheet2'!$AC:$AC, 1, FALSE), "N/A")
```

This is the whole idea behind using this formula:

- lookup the text string value in Sheet1 col.B (example: BajaTurkeyAvocado_6S_HeroRegular_Mobile)

[image]

- see if a value similar to this exists in Sheet2 col. AC (example: BajaTurkeyAvocado_6S_HeroRegular_Mobile.png is a match since it's a similar value)

[image]

- If it's a match, place Sheet2 col. AC value into Sheet1 col. E (This column holds my VLookup function, shown above):

[image]

I'm having a hard time implementing this VLookup function within my VBA Macro button. I don't want to have it written within the cells in column E.

This is what my goal is:

1. Click VBA button
2. runs vlookup as shown above for all values in column E Sheet1, based on the number of items to lookup in column B
3. Converts the lookup values into string in column E (rather than formula)

In short, just knowing how to convert a vlookup function written in a cell to a function written in a VBA macro button would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully, VBA automatically adjusts formulas when you apply them to a multi-cell range. So you can directly apply that formula you created to the entire column at once and not have to loop.

Then you can just do `.Value = .Value` to convert the formulas into strings.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim TargetRange As Range
    Set TargetRange = Sheet1.Range("E2:E" & lastrow)
    With TargetRange
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2&""*"", 'Sheet2'!$AC:$AC, 1, FALSE), ""N/A"")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

LastRow is used to trim the range to the used area since VLookUp is expensive and running it on an entire column (even the empty parts) will waste a lot of time.

Comment: did you see the OPs requirement _I don't want to have it written within the cells in column E._?

Comment: Thank you both, I ended up modifying Toddleson's code a bit, and it's working just fine! Thanks again!